# Disable atomikos logging from catalina.out

Tags: tomcat, logging, atomikos

I would like to set the atomikos log level to higher than INFO. Tomcat's catalina.out log file writes many INFO messages causing the transaction to take a long time to complete.

During start up, catalina.out contains:

```
18:11:51,481  INFO [main] AbstractUserTransactionService:16 - USING com.atomikos.icatch.console_log_level = WARN
```

During a transaction, the following is written many times to catalina.out.

```
18:12:05,072  INFO [http-8080-1] CompositeTransactionImp:16 - registerSynchronization ( com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy$JdbcRequeueSynchronization@7b60ad0 ) for transaction 127.0.0.1.tm0000100018  
18:12:05,072  INFO [http-8080-1] AtomikosConnectionProxy:16 - atomikos connection proxy for Pooled connection wrapping physical connection org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection@37955233: calling prepareStatement...  
18:12:05,073  INFO [http-8080-1] AtomikosConnectionProxy:16 - atomikos connection proxy for Pooled connection wrapping physical connection org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection@37955233: isClosed()...  
18:12:05,073  INFO [http-8080-1] AtomikosConnectionProxy:16 - atomikos connection proxy for Pooled connection wrapping physical connection org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection@37955233: calling getWarnings...  
18:12:05,073  INFO [http-8080-1] AtomikosConnectionProxy:16 - atomikos connection proxy for Pooled connection wrapping physical connection org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection@37955233: calling clearWarnings...  
18:12:05,073  INFO [http-8080-1] AtomikosConnectionProxy:16 - atomikos connection proxy for Pooled connection wrapping physical connection org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection@37955233: close()...
```

I have tried to set the atomikos level to WARN in conf/logging.properties, but the INFO logs are still being written. I have even removed the ConsoleHandler from logging.properties, but the catalina.out is still being written to.

In my webapp directory, I have updated log4j.xml to include the following, but still getting the logs.

```
<logger name="com.atomikos">
    <level value="ERROR"/>
</logger>
```

Answer (score 2):

In Atomikos 3.7, set the following system property :

```
com.atomikos.icatch.console_log_level=WARN
```

See [this link](http://www.atomikos.com/pub/Documentation/Tomcat7Integration35/jta.properties) for all Atomikos JTA properties

Starting with Atomikos 3.8, integration with log4j is much improved thru SLF4j.

See [configuring the logs](http://www.atomikos.com/Documentation/ConfiguringTheLogs)